Error during installing chatterbot on mac
I am trying to install chatterbot on my mac but I am getting the following error.
I have already upgraded pip and setuptools
My operating system is macOS Sonoma
running build_ext
            building 'thinc.linalg' extension
            creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
            creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/thinc
            clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/thinc_885e5c662e7c46bbb630a694ccba193d/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c thinc/linalg.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/thinc/linalg.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function -stdlib=libc++
            thinc/linalg.cpp:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
              #include "longintrepr.h"
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            1 error generated.
            error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
        Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [90 lines of output]
            BLIS_COMPILER? None
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
            creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/benchmark.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/about.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis/tests
            copying blis/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis/tests
            copying blis/tests/test_dotv.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis/tests
            copying blis/tests/test_gemm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis/tests
            copying blis/tests/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis/tests
            copying blis/cy.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/py.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            copying blis/cy.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/blis
            running build_ext
            clang: warning: optimization flag '-funroll-all-loops' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
            clang: error: unsupported argument 'core-avx2' to option '-march='
            unix
            py_compiler gcc
            {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/bulldozer/bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/generic/bli_cntx_init_generic.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_generic.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/haswell/bli_cntx_init_haswell.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_haswell.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/penryn/bli_cntx_init_penryn.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_penryn.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/piledriver/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_piledriver.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/sandybridge/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_sandybridge.o -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/config/steamroller/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_cntx_init_steamroller.o -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            clang -c /private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c -o /var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o -O3 -mavx2 -mfma -mfpmath=sse -march=core-avx2 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/darwin-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
                main()
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
                super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
                exec(code, locals())
              File "<string>", line 235, in <module>
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 104, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 184, in setup
                return run_commands(dist)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 200, in run_commands
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
                self.run_command("build")
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
                self.run_command(cmd_name)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 967, in run_command
                super().run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nyrgb806/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 359, in run
                self.build_extensions()
              File "<string>", line 105, in build_extensions
              File "<string>", line 184, in compile_objects
              File "<string>", line 198, in build_object
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
                raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
            subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['clang', '-c', '/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c', '-o', '/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/tmp8dn23z5p/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o', '-O3', '-mavx2', '-mfma', '-mfpmath=sse', '-march=core-avx2', '-fPIC', '-std=c99', '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L', '-DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6"', '-DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY', '-Iinclude/darwin-x86_64', '-I./frame/3/', '-I./frame/ind/ukernels/', '-I./frame/1m/', '-I./frame/1f/', '-I./frame/1/', '-I./frame/include', '-I/private/var/folders/ff/q23z9wb12bn04fh4hwj257vc0000gn/T/pip-install-sw2v23ns/blis_01880e10de4c4597855b74cbe7f7e3fa/blis/_src/include/darwin-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.


Actually what you are facing from your chatterbot not installing is dependency issues of longintrepr.h files of Cypthon. You are using Python 3.11 on your macOS based on your traceback Error call. And that file is not installed in your Python 3.11 which Chatterbot needs to work. To make your installation work, kindly downgrade your Python from 3.11 to 3.8. Then run this on your terminal:
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4

However, if you insist on keeping your Python 3.11 which you are currently using on your OS, you can install a third-party dependency of chatterbot which works pretty well for version 3.11 and above of Python, the developer, ShoneGK, has taken good care of this issue our Python community face in installing and using chatterbot. Chatterbot has not been receiving updates/issue resolution for more than 2 years now.
Run this command on your bash, and you are good to go:

pip install git+https://github.com/ShoneGK/ChatterPy

# Since Chatterbot also requires a corpus of text to use as training data, you can download the corpus, using this.
pip install chatterbot-corpus


Now, your installation should work perfectly, I believe. Good luck.
